# Importing RxJS 6 in browser?

Tags: javascript, npm, rxjs, jspm, unpkg

Now that [all modern browser support javascript modules](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module), I'm trying out  `import`ing code right in the browser. We can get `npm` modules from [unpkg.com](http://unpkg.com), and I've found the [jspm](https://jspm.io/) project, which wraps `npm` modules into a format that can be consumed by the browser.

But I'm still having problems, most notably with [RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs). RxJS, as of version 6, recommends you import constructors and operators like this:

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

But if I try to do that in the browser with:

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/operators';
```

I get errors along these lines:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/operators' does not provide an export named 'map'

I can get around it by importing the whole `rxjs` module and teasing out what I need, like I would using a CDN:

```
import rxjs from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6';
const { Observable } = rxjs;
import operators from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/operators';
const { map } = operators;
```

but this defeats what the Rx team is trying to do to decrease the final bundle size, etc.

I'm sure this isn't just an RxJS problem.

What is the solution here moving forward to get our dev javascript (imports directly into the browser) to look like what we'd finally want to pass to a bundler?

Comment: Even more difficult seems to be using the `import 'rxjs/add/operator...` syntax... I'm sure the answer is not simple, what I'd investigate (would I have some time on hand) is an approach to package individual modules of rxjs into individual es6-compatible units. I think it can be achieved using something like `rollup`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The es6 module export syntax is inside the subfolder `_esm2015`. So you need to import:

```js
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/_esm2015';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/_esm2015/operators';
```

---

Sadly you can't just install *rxjs* with `npm install rxjs@6` and then `import` in the browser, because the distribution source is missing the file extension `.js` in the `import` statements: https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.3.3/dist/esm2015/index.js.

But the browser needs the file extensions for `import` (at the moment):   (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules#specifiers):

```js
// Not supported (yet):
import {shout} from 'jquery';
import {shout} from 'lib.mjs';
import {shout} from 'modules/lib.mjs';

// Supported:
import {shout} from './lib.mjs';
import {shout} from '../lib.mjs';
import {shout} from '/modules/lib.mjs';
import {shout} from 'https://simple.example/modules/lib.mjs';
```

There is also an **issue** for this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4416 .

- Sidenote: https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/_esm2015 will resolve to https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/_esm2015/index.js

For now you have to rely on https://jspm.io or make your own bundle (e.g. with *rollup* as suggested by @Ovidiu Dolha).

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simple rxjs starter example stackblitz:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gm1qso

In short:

Make sure you have a script to add the rxjs js file (for example from a CDN)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.1.0/rxjs.umd.js">
```

Everything is imported under the rxjs namespace, so to a simple example usage:

```
rxjs.of(1, 2, 3)
  .subscribe(x => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerText = 'Data: ' + x;
    document.body.appendChild(element)
  },
  err => { },
  () => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerText = 'All done';
    document.body.appendChild(element)
  });
```

Comment: I think this answer is not really answering the original question. The problem is not only loading rxjs, but loading it in an ESModules-friendly way.

Comment: And if you want to use an operator: `var tap = rxjs.operators.tap;`  and then `rxjs.of(1,2,3).pipe(tap(value=>console.log(value)))`

Comment: `const` may even better, `const tap = rxjs.operators.tap; `

Comment: further improve with destructuring, like `const { debounceTime, tap } = rxjs.operators`, and now you can add to the list as required

Answer (score -2):

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");

var obs1 = rxjs.fromEvent(button, "click");

var obs2 = rxjs.interval(1000);

// obs2.subscribe((val) => {
//   console.log(val);
// });


obs1.pipe(rxjs.switchMap(() => obs2)).subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rxjs@7.8.1/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
        <script defer src='main.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="btn">
            Click Me
        </button>
    </body>

    </html>
```